# How to make something happen when a key is held down in p5.js

Tags: keyboard, draw, p5.js

I'm trying to make a simple drawing program where the color and size of the line being drawn changes when the 'e' key is held down. However, when I try to use `keyPressed`, it only executes once, resulting in a single blue dot being drawn instead of changing the whole line. Basically, what I need to know is how to make something happen when a key is held, because it only registers the press once. This is what I have so far:

```javascript
    function keyTyped() {
      if (key === 'e') {
        if (mouseY < 417) {
          fill(0,0,255,100);
          ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,5,5);
        }
      }
    }
```

instead of

```javascript
   function draw() {
     if (mouseY < 417) {
       noStroke();
       fill(0,100);
       ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @Kevin Workman everything got solved in the end, thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Note that you can mark a question as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Does this still need an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could just check from the `draw()` function, like this:

```javascript
function draw() {
  if (keyIsPressed && key == 'e') {
    noStroke();
    fill(0,100);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
  }
}
```

Or you could create a variable that tracks whether the key is being pressed. Set it to `true` from the `keyPressed()` function, and set it to `false` in the `keyReleased()` function. Then check the variable in the `draw()` function.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Comment: That definitely helps, but it's still drawing semi-transparent black circles over them: http://i66.tinypic.com/2d1n668.png -- Any suggestions?

Comment: @KatK That's exactly what I would expect this code to do. What were you expecting? Note that if you want to clear out old frames, you should call the `background()` function at the top of `draw()`.

Comment: When I call background, I just get a blue dot that follows my mouse without leaving a trail.

Comment: @KatK Yeah, again, that's exactly what I would expect. You're only ever drawing circles. If you clear them, you'll only get one circle. If you don't clear them, you'll get a bunch of circles. What exactly are you expecting differently?

Comment: I want it to turn from a line of semi-transparent circles to a line of small blue circles, without the semi-transparent circles.

Comment: @KatK Then just change what you're passing into the `fill()` function. You're using `fill(0, 100)` right now, which will give you a black but transparent color. Use `fill(0, 0, 255)` for blue.

Comment: @KatK If you have follow-up questions, please post an updated [mcve] in a new question post, and we'll go from there.